# About dependencies using requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

Let's suppose I am in the following context.

I need to use
`backbone` which requires `underscore` and `jquery`
and
`backbone.marionette` which requires `backbone`, `underscore` and `jquery`

should I write this code (1) or the following (2)

---

(1)

```
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        marionette: {
            deps: ['backbone', 'underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'marionette'
        },
    }
```

---

(2)

```
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        marionette: {
            deps: ['backbone'],
            exports: 'marionette'
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include underscore and jquery in marionette's dependencies, because they will have been loaded already for Backbone. A couple of corrections to (2) though:

1. You should shim underscore, and export '_' because it's expected to be in the global namespace.
2. Marionette is a Backbone plugin, so you don't need to export anything or you can export 'Backbone.Marionette' (see http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

This is how I would do it:

```
shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    marionette: {
        deps: ['backbone'],
        exports: 'Backbone.Marionette'
}
```